# Bullets don't have force added at a fixed speed? How to properly shoot independently form left and right sides in 2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, transform, rigid-bodies

I'm kind of new to coding, about a year of experience. I can't figure out why my script won't add force to the bullets I shoot at a fixed speed. It seems to depend on how fast the player moves, but I used 2 different variables for speed and movementSpeed, so I don't know why it does this. How would I go about fixing this? I was also trying to make it so I can shoot independently from the left and right sides when the character faces that direction, but it doesn't seem to work. When I try to fix it, it either throws an error, the bullet stays in place when instantiated, or the bullet always goes to the right. What's the proper way of doing this if I did it wrong?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Bullet;
    public float sec = 2f;

    public float speed = 80;

    public GameObject Enemy;

    public Transform spawnPoint;

    public Rigidbody2D bulletRB;

    private float timeBtwShots;
    public float startTimeBtwShots;

    public AudioSource Gunshot;

    public Animator animator;

    private float vert;
    private float horiz;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (gameObject.tag == "Bullet")

            this.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        StartCoroutine(LateCall());

        IEnumerator LateCall()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec);

            this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
       
        
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D Other)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        } 
    }

    IEnumerator ShootingAnim()
    {
       
        timeBtwShots = startTimeBtwShots;
        Gunshot.Play();
        animator.SetBool("IsShooting", true);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);

        animator.SetBool("IsShooting", false);


    }

    void Update()
    {
        horiz = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        vert = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Instantiate(bulletRB, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        

        if (timeBtwShots <= 0)
        {

                bulletRB.AddForce(transform.TransformDirection(new Vector2(horiz, vert)).normalized * speed);

                StartCoroutine(ShootingAnim());
            }
        else
        {
            timeBtwShots -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (gameObject.tag == "Bullet")
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject, 1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I did a complete rewrite because I way overcomplicated the code.
Here's the final scripts:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float MovementSpeed = 1;
    public float JumpForce = 1;
    public float jumpTime = 1f;

    public Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;

    private bool facingRight;

    public float sec = 2f;

    public Vector2 bulletPos;

    public GameObject bulletToRight, bulletToLeft;

    public Transform spawnPoint;

    public Rigidbody2D bulletRB;

    public AudioSource Gunshot;

    float horizontalMove = 0f;

    public float fireRate = 0.5f;
    float nextFire = 0f;

    // public AudioSource Jump;

    public Animator animator;

    void HandleMovement(float horizontal)
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3(horizontal, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * MovementSpeed;
        animator.SetFloat("velX", (horizontal));
    }

    void Flip(float horizontal)
    {
        if (horizontal < 0 && !facingRight || horizontal > 0 && facingRight)
        {
            facingRight = !facingRight;

            Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;

            theScale.x *= -1;

            transform.localScale = theScale;

            transform.position += new Vector3(horizontal, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * MovementSpeed;

            horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * MovementSpeed;

            animator.SetFloat("velX", (horizontalMove));
        } 
    }

    IEnumerator ShootingAnim()
    {

        
        animator.SetBool("IsShooting", true);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);

        animator.SetBool("IsShooting", false);


    }

    void Update()
    {

        animator.SetFloat("velX", Mathf.Abs(horizontalMove));

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && Mathf.Abs(_rigidbody.velocity.y) < 0.001f)
        {
            _rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", true);
            // Jump.Play();
        }

        if (Mathf.Abs(_rigidbody.velocity.y) == 0f)
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", false);
        }

        if ((_rigidbody.velocity.x) >= 0.01f || (_rigidbody.velocity.x <= -0.01f)) 
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsRunning", true);
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && Time.time > nextFire)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ShootingAnim());
            nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
            Fire();

        }


        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        HandleMovement(horizontal);

        Flip(horizontal);



    }

    void Fire()
    {
        bulletPos = spawnPoint.position;
        if (!facingRight)
        {
            bulletPos += new Vector2(+0.02f, 0f);
            Instantiate(bulletToRight, bulletPos, Quaternion.identity);
            Gunshot.Play();
        } else
        {
            bulletPos += new Vector2(-0.02f, 0f);
            Instantiate(bulletToLeft, bulletPos, Quaternion.identity);
            Gunshot.Play();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Here's the BulletScript:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Bullet;

    public Transform spawnPoint;

    public Rigidbody2D bulletRB;

    public float velX = 5f;

    float velY = 0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bulletRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D Other)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        } 
    }

    private void Update()
    {

        bulletRB.velocity = new Vector2(velX, velY);
        Destroy(gameObject, 3f);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using input to determine the bullet's direction, store the direction the player is looking. Add a new Vector2 called "currentDirection" and default it to Vector2.right or something. When you calculate the movement on the player, do this:

```
if (!Mathf.Approximately(horiz, 0) || !Mathf.Approximately(vert, 0))
    currentDirection = new Vector2(horiz, vert).normalized;
```

You'll notice the first line checks if either line is NOT zero. I do this because if both inputs are 0 then the direction with be zero as well. We only want to save the last direction the player input, not a lack of direction.

Next, bullets should also have a direction variable. When you spawn a bullet, set the direction on the bullet to currentDirection. You want to do this only when spawning the bullet. If you set the bullet's direction to the player's current input every frame then it would change direction based on the player's input constantly.

Then just tell the bullet to move in it's assigned direction. Often people will just change it's rotation to match the direction and tell it to move forward, but that can depend on how you want your art to look for the bullet.

---

Also extremely important but unrelated: You need to put all rigidbody code in FixedUpdate. Physics only happens during fixed updates so doing anything physics related outside of that can cause issues. However, when you do that keep your input checks in Update. Since FixedUpdates don't happen every frame, input can be lost if you put them in FixedUpdate. So, add some input variables and in update do

```
jumpInput = Input.GetButtonDown("Jump");
horiz = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
vert = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
```

then in FixedUpdate do your physics like:

```
if (jumpInput && Mathf.Abs(_rigidbody.velocity.y) < 0.001f)
```

Comment: Okay, I updated my code. I also added everything to the bullet script since someone on the Unity Discord suggested that. It won't shoot my bullets at all now though. It doesn't instantiate the bullet even when I say to in Update. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's too much I don't know. What is the bullet script on? Did you try a Debug.Log in different parts of the methods to see if anything is being called?

Comment: The bullet script is on the bullet. Before a lot of the bullet-related code was on the player. And I didn’t try that. I will try that now.

Comment: Ahh, your problem is that your code that instantiates the bullet is on the bullet... which isn't instantiated yet. The idea is that you need to have your player physics and shooting stuff on the player and keep all the things the bullet does on the bullet script since it's on the bullet. So jumping, movement, shooting, etc move to a player script on the player. The bullet's movement, physics, collision should all be on the bullet script.

Comment: Okay. So I ALMOST have it. Still having the original issue though of the bullets not having any speed/velocity. They only have speed/velocity if my player moves in the direction he's shooting. Otherwise it just instantiates and is stationary.

Comment: Here is code for PlayerController: [PlayerController Script](https://hatebin.com/gepqaonsjh)

Comment: Here is updated code for Bullet Script: [BulletScript](https://hatebin.com/tyvqaiiemt)

Comment: Updated my answer. I think this will solve it. The two relevant problems I see in your code are 1. You're checking input every frame on the bullet when you should be setting it once when spawning. 2. If you aren't pressing anything then the direction would be 0. The solution to both these issues is saving the input direction only when there is actually input and then applying that direction on spawning the bullet.